# Arduino Nano with CH340 reboots on OS X El Capitan

Tags: arduino-nano

I installed OS X El Capitan beta on my Macbook. Now my Nano-sized Chinese Arduino operating on CH340 chip reboots the laptop when USB is unplugged. While plugged, it works fine, I can upload sketches and send/receive data via Serial.

I've tried reinstalling the CH340 driver and running the following command as per [this solution](https://www.reddit.com/r/arduino/comments/3dfr2e/ch340g_arduinos_with_osx_el_capitan/) and it didn't help:

```
sudo nvram boot-args="kext-dev-mode=1 rootless=0"
```

I appreciate any ideas...

Comment: If I may ask, how did you get the Arduino to be detected by the computer? Since I updated to El Capitan, I've been unable to get the Arduino detected on the computer.

Comment: @duci9y Frankly, I did nothing special. I just upgraded from Yosemite to El Capitan, plugged in my Arduino, did a bit of coding as normal, unplugged it and boom, my Mac reboots after about 3 seconds.

Comment: @duci9y It turns out I didn't have the latest Beta. I now updated to the latest and now my CH340-based Arduino doesn't get detected as well! :)

Comment: Ah… so we are at the same place now. I'll post a question about it, maybe someone would know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a new signed driver for OS-X El Capitan and Yosemite. This is all you want.

http://kig.re/2014/12/31/how-to-use-arduino-nano-mini-pro-with-CH340G-on-mac-osx-yosemite.html

Answer (score 1):

The command you ran only disables driver signing verification, which means OSX stops blocking it. If it is crashing it is likely to be either a bug in OSX, or a bug in the driver. My guess is it is a bug in the driver and you'll probably have to wait until they release an updated version that is compatible with El Capitan.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I didn't have the latest Beta. I now updated to the latest and now my CH340-based Arduino doesn't get detected at all! Pretty much in line with everyone else complaining all over internet.

Answer (score 1):

Check this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zuRukW7o0A

- Reboot and press CMD+R immediately after reboot to enter in Recovery Mode
- Open Terminal from Recovery mode
- Run the command csrutil enable --without kext
- Reboot
- Install driver

Comment: helped me, thanks. First I ran csrutil disable and it worked, however I feel better with your suggestion because it doesn't disable Protection System

Answer (score 0):

If you have macOS High Sierra like mine 10.13.4
This is work for me
https://github.com/awangga/NFCReader